# Problema com @Autowire Spring + Hibernate e Junit

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, junit, spring-data

Boa noite, estou tentando criar um projeto utilizando Hibernate e Spring, obtive sucesso criando algumas configurações, inclusive consegui gerar o banco de dados através da inicialização da aplicação utilizando o Spring, porém estou "empacado" na criação dos meus DAO's, utilizo a anotação @Autowired para injetar uma sessionFactory do hibernate criada no contexto do spring na minha classe DaoGenerico, mas ao tentar realizar testes recebo o erro NullPointerException quando a sessionFactory tenta recuperar uma sessao através do método getSession(), abaixo seguem alguns códigos:

Interfaces:

DaoI

```
     public interface DaoI<T> {

    public void persistir(T objeto);

    public void excluir (T objeto);

    public T get(Integer id);

    public List<T> listar(int de, int ate);

}
```

DaoUsuarioI

```
 public interface DaoUsuarioI<T> extends DaoI<T>{

    public void addUsuario(Usuario usuario);

    public void removerUsuario(Usuario usuario);

    public Usuario getUsuario(Integer id);

    public void atualizaUsuario(Usuario usuario);

    public List<Usuario> getUsuarios();

}
```

Classes:

DaoGenerico

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public abstract class DaoGenerico<T> implements DaoI<T> {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getSession(){return getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();}

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {return sessionFactory;}

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;}

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    protected abstract Class getClazz();

    public void persistir(T objeto) {
        getSession().persist(objeto);
    }

    public void excluir(T objeto) {
        getSession().delete(objeto);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T get(Integer id) {
        return (T) getSession().get(getClazz(), id);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> listar(int de, int ate) {
        return (List<T>) getSession().createCriteria(getClazz()).setMaxResults(ate).setFirstResult(de).list();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> listar() {
        return (List<T>) getSession().createCriteria(getClazz()).list();

    }
```

DaoUsuario

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS)
@Repository("daoUsuario")
public class DaoUsuario extends DaoGenerico<Usuario> implements DaoUsuarioI {


    public void addUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        persistir(usuario);
    }

    public void removerUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        removerUsuario(usuario);
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario(Integer id) {
        return get(id);
    }

    public void atualizaUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        Session s = super.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        s.update(usuario);
    }

    public List<Usuario> getUsuarios() {
        return listar();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    protected Class getClazz() {
        return Usuario.class;
    }

}
```

O meu contexto esta configurado no arquivo spring-data.xml, segue abaixo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">


        <context:annotation-config />

        <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.springframework.persistencia" />

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </bean>

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

        <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
            <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="user" value="*******" />
            <property name="password" value="********" />
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springframework"/>

            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="30" />
            <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1"/>
            <property name="maxIdleTime" value="120"/>
            <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="10"/>
            <property name="initialPoolSize" value="1" />
        </bean> 

        <bean id="sessionFactory" name="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.com.springframework.entidades" />
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>



        <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
</beans>
```

Estou tentando criar testes com o JUnit para verificar o funcionamento das classes acima, porém sem sucesso... alguem poderia ajudar?

Obrigado...

Answer (score 1):

O Spring não tem como instanciar ou injetar algo na sua classe DaoGenerico porque ela é abstrata. Suas opções são:

1. Fazer seu DaoGenerico deixar de ser abstrato e de ser pai de DaoUsuario, receber a SessionFactory na DaoUsuario (no construtor, é muito mais indicado do que injetar direto no campo) e instanciar o DaoGenerico, tendo uma instância na DaoUsuario. Assim você pode usar ele onde quiser, ao invés de herdar inúmeros metódos que muito provavelmente DaoUsuario não devria ter, mas tem (composição ao invés de herança).
2. Manter o DaoGenerico abstrato e pai dos outros Daos, receber a SessionFactory na DaoUsuario (lembrando, via construtor) e ae você faz um super(sessionFactory), e tudo funciona. Não é uma opção ruim, mas a forma como os métodos estão expostos no código atual me faz preferir a primeira opção.

Aproveitando, tenho outras observações sobre o código:

- caso você só tenha uma implementação de DaoUsuarioI, você não precisa da interface, já que ela é monomórfica. Instancie o objeto diretamente ao invés da referência pela interface e remova-a.
- tire o 'I' dos nomes das suas interfaces, essa é uma convenção terrível que existe no .net, não a siga.
- uma interface para um Dao genérico não faz sentido algum. A menos que você implemente um Dao para o Hibernate, um para JPA, e por aí vai.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Juliano, fiz umas alterações seguindo alguns de seus conselhos e fiz "a coisa" funcionar aqui, inclusive nos testes com JUnit... estou aprendendo Spring a alguns dias, mas para esse caso acho que me falta conceito relacionado ao uso de Generics para construir algo mais elaborado e que funcione. Consegui fazer funcionar criando a camada de persistencia de uma maneira mais "arcaica", vc tem algum link/material que possa me ajudar a entender melhor como utilizar Generics para aplicar de maneira interessante sobre minha camada de persistencia?

Comment: Acho que não. Não me lembro de algum material sobre generics usado dessa forma especifica. Mas sobre o DaoGenerico você encontra sem dificuldades :)

Comment: Opa Juliano, consegui implementar o código postado, o Spring consegue realizar injeção em classes abstratas, eu estava errando na hora de instanciar as classes criadas acima... o certo seria através da interface que representa a mesma.